# End life of [liveserver]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, burninate-request

Today I ran into the tag [liveserver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/liveserver) which has 0 followers, 45 questions and no wiki.

It seems that it is ambiguously used for questions related to problems after switching from a localhost environment to a production server, often mentioned as "going live" or questions related to NPM package as mentioned by @makoto.

I suggest maybe we just burn it. Or someone who's a [liveserver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/liveserver) specialist could take their time to update the tag.

**Update**: the tag has been recreated/updated and stands now for:

> Live-server is a package for Atom for launching http servers with
> live-reload capabilities.

is this what we want?

https://stackoverflow.com/tags/liveserver/info

**Update2**: above link was removed, [liveserver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/liveserver) has now 0 followers and 0 questions.

**Update3**: the tag [liveserver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/liveserver) has spawned again since Mar 11, 2021, with 118 questions by today

Comment: You sure that it's not referring to something in an NPM package?  A quick look suggested that may be the case.

Comment: @Makoto bnot in at least 50% on the first page. anyway please feel free to update the tag-wiki.

Comment: Note: Just because a tag doesn't have a corresponding tag-wiki doesn't mean we don't need/want it.

Comment: @Rizier123 I know, that's why I suggest someone updates the WiKi, so you know when to use it

Comment: @Rizier123 I also wouldn't mind if you roll back your edit. I suggested for discussion "maybe we just burn it (upvote to burn) or someone who's a liveserver specialist could take their time to update the tag (downvote not to burn).

Comment: I edited out the (upvote to burn) and (downvote to burn) parentheticals. It's out of place to proscribe your own meanings to others' votes, and you can't restrict folks to only vote for those two reasons. If you want a strawpoll I would write an answer.

Comment: TItle suggestion, because the current pun isn't good enough: *"Can we end [liveserver]'s life?"*

Comment: so what are we going to do now? I've just looked at the tag again, it was not updated lately...

Comment: I've destroyed it again.

Comment: @Braiam,  it's still there

Comment: 0 questions tagged.

Comment: It seems it's now being used to refer to the (popular) VS Code Live Server extension: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ritwickdey.LiveServer. There's an [atom-liveserver] tag... maybe retag to [vscode-liveserver]?

Comment: @GinoMempin looking into the first 10 newest questions right now, live-server refers 2 times to some visual-studio related Q. The other 8 to other topics.

Answer (score 32):

vote up here to **get rid of the tag completely**

Answer (score -5):

vote up here **if you think the tag should stay**

(I personally have no view on this but there needs to be an opposing post. Counting upvotes and downvotes on Joe's could potentially introduce a bias because of the differing rep requirements for the two actions)

Comment: It already has a downvote; What would that mean? *puts on thinking cap*

Comment: @BhargavRao - MartinSmith has a really good point. There is certainly difference in  "_do you agree to burn_" (yes, no) and "_do you agree to keep_" (yes, no) different statements encourages to different behaviour.

Comment: @davidkonrad also the constituency that can vote "yes" is larger than those that can vote "no" anyway (anyone with rep >= 15 and < 125 can only vote one way). It would be nice if meta had proper support for polls as the Q and A format is not ideal.

Comment: dude this answer is virtually a copy of mine!

Comment: Looks like hunting for rep went totally wrong

Comment: @SherKhan There is no visible rep on meta. Upvotes and downvotes on this answer don't alter my displayed reputation as that it is from actions on the main site.

Comment: Ooops, my bad :P