# Automatically append guidance to questions tagged [burninate-request]

Tags: feature-request, burninate-system

I notice [this answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/319879/73226) on a recent burninate-request expressing frustration that some process has not been followed.

I'm a reasonably regular participant on meta and wasn't aware of either of the two links posted in the answer.

Without this knowledge the question just looks like a moderately popular call to action so it's not surprising that someone acted upon it.

**Feature Request:**

Every question tagged "burninate-request" should get a notice automatically appended with a warning that it should not be unilaterally acted upon by would-be helpful citizens and a link to the desired procedure.

Comment: Similar to the banner that appears for close/protected/locked questions but burnination rules instead?

Comment: @ryanyuyu yes, that's what I had in mind. Though probably a link to the rules rather than the actual rules unless they can be made much more concise.

Comment: The point is, if there are not so many questions (< 100?) and there is enough support I don't see much of a problem if someone takes it on. The  reason the process came up was because the impact larger burnination efforts have and the number of people involved if you want to pull it off within considerable amount of time. In the proposal from Shog9 he does mention the [status-review] as an initial step that currently isn't effective as we are testing the other parts of the process. In that sense your question beats me by a couple of weeks.

Comment: If someone came up with a decent message+link to show in the banner, I'd probably support this feature-request.

Comment: @rene So if the workflow should be different for < 100 tagged questions this should be documented in the official guidance linked to.

Comment: This is the answer from Shog I'm talking about: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/307068/make-it-easier-to-prevent-new-questions-being-added-in-a-tag/307124#307124

Comment: You beat me to it! Thanks for making that FR, guidance is really needed when it comes to burnination. Lone wolfing really isn't a nice outcome when there's large parts of SO to cure like that. @rene I still think that unless well-informed a user shouldn't take on tag removal by themselves. Guidance is needed to at least provide useful pointers to users with the motivation to fix parts of SO. A burnination explanation + process banner would achieve this very well.

Comment: I did ask myself if it either needs a meta post or added to the tag wiki. It really doesn't matter, nobody reads that. It is only our task to judge any  burnination post against a couple of criteria and let's pray that everybody votes using those criteria. You can't prevent users that run into such meta-post and think it is viable to take it on. No matter how much process we invent here.

Comment: Step 1 to a formal post is the evaluation of the process which I posted [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/323121/evaluation-of-socvrs-burnination-process).

Comment: Step 2 is completed, find the FAQ-proposed post of the process [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/324070/what-is-the-process-for-burninating-tags)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

That is already proposed as step 1 by [Shog9](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/811/shog9) in the curently tested [burnination process](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/307068/make-it-easier-to-prevent-new-questions-being-added-in-a-tag/307124#307124).

> 1. When a [burninate-request](/questions/tagged/burninate-request) is posted, it will be marked [status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review) until/unless it scores at least 20. If it never achieves this score, then it should not be acted on; don't interpret apathy as a sign of support.

Because that process is currently headed by the [SOCVR](https://github.com/SO-Close-Vote-Reviewers/SOCVR-RoomInformation/blob/master/burnination.md), we didn't fancy re-tagging all requests and have post-notices added on top of all currently unloved [burninate requests](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&pagesize=50&q=%5bburninate-request%5d%20closed%3ano%20-%5bstatus-*%5d%20hasaccepted%3ano). We picked 5 tags to burninate from a similar list of tags to determine (with help from both moderators and community managers) whether this is a process that could work. After the evaluation of those 5 tags, I'll finalize a [faq-proposed](/questions/tagged/faq-proposed) post for the burnination process.

In the meantime, I think it is wise to judge both new and existing burnination requests to make sure they meet [minimal requirements](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/239191/306392) and vote and comment on such meta posts accordingly. As we are already doing, right?
The [punniness](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/295583/why-do-people-have-a-little-pun-with-their-retag-and-burninate-requests) of the title shouldn't be taken into consideration.

If you find a lone wolf in the review queue, maybe point them to the guidelines.  Make sure they're not just removing the tag while ignoring other aspects of proper burnination.  If anybody reads the tag-wiki for [burninate-request](/questions/tagged/burninate-request), we might add that to the tag wiki too.

**Burnination isn't only about removing the tag from a question**

This is the simple task list we post when a burnination request is taken on:

> You can help out by reviewing the questions and answers in these tags and:
>
> - flag or close questions that are duplicate/off-topic/unclear/too broad/opinion based;
> - filter on these tags in the Close Vote Queue and review;
> - vote on the questions and its answers;
> - delete vote the question or answer(s) if there is nothing of value;
> - editing to add value (re-tag), or;
> - flag obsolete comments

#### We graduated!

The burnination process has graduated and is now in its own meta post [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/324070/what-is-the-process-for-burninating-tags)

Comment: Sounds good, I doubt people read the tag wiki as well though. Perhaps a small guidance notice would still be in order outlining the process as even the notion that an upvote is a motion to burn and a downvote means not to burn encountered some opposition here  http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/319624/end-life-of-liveserver#comment326648_319624 with the suggestion that answers be used for that purpose instead.

Comment: Let me get a feed up in the SOCVR or somewhere else so we can add that comment or notice to new incoming posts and maybe skim the recent ones to do something similar

Comment: done [here](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/29603424#29603424)